# Concentrating n ammounts of char arrays into a single char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, merge, char, printf

I am trying to merge a lot of char arrays into a single one. **My task is to change float array into a char array to be sent as a line of data via TCP/IP socket**, so I thought to use ***sprintf*** to print float array values into a char array and then merge those arrays into a single char array, I wrote a little algorithm, but the data does not form into a single line of data and overwrites the last input, what am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
 * Mock data loop - a loop where data is created
 * String loop - a loop where a single word is merged into a sentance
 * Formating loop - a loop where floats are converted into char arrays
 !!! - The place where things go wrong (I think)
*/

using namespace std;

int main(){

    float data[5];                      // Mock data array
    char tmp[10];                       // Temprorary array, where a word (flaot value) is stored
    char text[256];                     // String array, where words are stored into a single sentance
    int n=5;                            // Size of mock data
    int i, j, k;                        // Loop counters

    // Mock data loop
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        data[i] = float(i);
        printf("Data: %f \n", data[i]);
    }

    printf("------------------------- \n");
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// !!!
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++){                  // String loop
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){                 // Mock data loop
            for (k = 0; k < 10; k++){           // Formating loop
                sprintf(tmp, "%f", data[j]);
                printf("Sprintf: %s \n", tmp);
                text[i + k] = tmp[k];
            }
        }
        printf("Text %d : %s \n", i, text);
        i = i + 9;
        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// !!!
    printf("------------------------- \n");
    printf("Text: %s \n", text);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate the help, guys!

P.S. I am trying **not** to use any C++ functions, because I am working with a microcontroller, this code has been written in MS Visual 2013, so I use *#include*  and *std::cin.get();* to halt the console and see the results.

Comment: Why not step through the code in the debugger to see what the problem is ?

Comment: Why do you call `sprintf()` 10 times on the same float?

Comment: Also use a C compiler when doing C.

Comment: "change float array into a char array to be sent as a line of data via TCP/IP socket" This doesn't make any sense. Why do you need a character array? To print the float number as ASCII letters or do you need the character array simply because you want to send the data byte by byte? Those two cases are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell by your code, you're reserving 10 characters in the line for each float value (you do `i++`, but also `i += 9`). What if the string representation for the float requires more positions? Your `tmp` will overflow and your counting will be off.

Here's an attempt that doesn't use 10 positions, but just as many as necessary. On the receiving side you'd have to split by spaces and `sscanf()` to get the floats back. The code also checks for buffer overflows. I hope that I've understood your question correctly and that this helps...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    float data[5];              /* Mock data */
    char text[256];             /* Line of data */
    int i;

    /* Build up mock data */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        data[i] = i * 3 + 3.1415729;

    /* Stuff int text */
    text[0] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        char tmp[100];          /* Conversion buffer, should be large enough */
        if (snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp), "%f ", data[i]) >= sizeof(tmp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "conversion buffer overflow\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (strlen(text) + strlen(tmp) >= sizeof(text)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "text buffer overflow\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcat(text, tmp);
    }

    printf("Built up text: %s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this will work perfectly, oh and about those 10 positions, I just needed the accuracy of float to be 10 positions, I am taking measurements in float values, so there is a bit of precisions that needs to be dealt with, I think even 10 is over doing it a bit.